# ASP.NET 6 MVC select input does not work when submitting form in POST request

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I have an app in ASP.NET MVC and I want to add a 'Ride'. To do is I show the user a form with 2 selects but when I press the submit button, the data in the HttpPost request comes back empty, and I get an error in my view saying the field is null.

Any help?

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
        {
            var trains = await _trainRepository.GetAllAsync();
            var stations = await _stationRepository.GetAllAsync();

            var rideViewModel = new RideViewModel()
            {
                Ride = new Ride(),
                Trains = trains,
                Stations = stations
            };

            return View(rideViewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(RideViewModel rideViewModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(rideViewModel);
            }
            _rideRepository.Add(rideViewModel.Ride);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

ViewModel

```
    public class RideViewModel
    {
        public Ride Ride { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Train> Trains { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Station> Stations { get; set; }
    }
```

View

```
@model RideViewModel


<div class="container">
    <form method="post" asp-action="Create">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Ride.Train">Select a train</label>
            <select asp-for="Ride.Train" class="custom-select mr-sm-2">
                @foreach (var item in Model.Trains)
                {
                    <option value="@item.Id">@item.Id</option>
                }
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="Ride.Train" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Ride.Station">Select a station</label>
            <select asp-for="Ride.Station" class="custom-select mr-sm-2">
                @foreach (var item in Model.Stations)
                {
                    <option value="@item.Id">@item.City</option>
                }
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="Ride.Station" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit station</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: Have you debugged through your HttpGet method? What is `trains` and `stations` set to? Also calling your GET method `Create` isn't very logical.

Comment: Can `var trains = await _trainRepository.GetAllAsync();` get the correct data in your create action?